# How to retrieve the content of an email's attachment just like it shows when I .ToString() it?

Tags: c#, mailkit, mimekit

I can't seem to find any method that returns me just the encoded part of this e.ToString() output.

('e' is a MimeEntity with 1 singular email attachment)

This is what the output looks like:

```
X-MimeKit-Warning: Do NOT use ToString() to serialize entities! Use one of the WriteTo() methods instead!
Content-Type: image/png; name="px.png"
Content-Description: px.png
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="px.png"; size=119;
        creation-date="Tue, 06 Apr 2021 09:24:23 GMT";
        modification-date="Tue, 06 Apr 2021 09:24:56 GMT"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACx
jwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAMSURBVBhXY/j//z8ABf4C/qc1gYQAAAAASUVO
RK5CYII=
```

The only thing I'm looking for would be this part:

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACx
jwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAMSURBVBhXY/j//z8ABf4C/qc1gYQAAAAASUVO
RK5CYII=
```

Comment: Did *Do NOT use ToString() to serialize entities! Use one of the WriteTo() methods instead!* prove to be helpful?

Comment: @rene the WriteTo() method outputs everything that the ToString() method outputs, except for that "warning" sort of line.

Comment: Did you try the overload that accepts a boolean, and set that boolean to true? http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/M_MimeKit_MimeEntity_WriteTo_4.htm

Comment: Oh... Looks like I didn't try that, when I read the documentation I didn't really understand all that "CancellationToken" thing so I decided not to touch that. Thank you rene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`WriteTo` overload](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/M_MimeKit_MimeEntity_WriteTo_4.htm) that accepts an boolean to indicate if you only want the content of the MimeEnity.

Like so

```
// 'e' is a MimeEntity

var ms = new MemoryStream();
e.WriteTo(ms, true); // no need to provide an cancellationtoken.

// ms will have only the content here
```

The third parameter `cancellationtoken` is null by default so you won't need to provide an instance of an token. That becomes only relevant if you want to gracefully end the WriteTo operation before it finished.